# Calling constructor on an object created via Object.create() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to use `Object.create(prototype)` to create an object that inherits the values of another object. However, the prototype object is an ES6 object that has a class and a constructor. I want to be able to call the constructor on the newly-created object; however it appears that no matter how I do it, the constructor returns a new object instead of modifying the existing object.

So for example:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public readonly name: string) {}
}
const parent = new Foo('test');
const child = Object.create(parent);
parent.constructor.call(child, 'other');

expect(child.name).toBe('other'); // FAIL - name is 'test'
```

I realize what I am trying to do may seem odd, so here's some context - these objects are being deserialized from a JSON file, where the serialized data allows for prototype inheritance - i.e. one JSON object can inherit the properties of another; moreover, they can also be re-serialized back into JSON preserving this relationship, which means that I don't want to simply `Object.assign()` all of the properties of the parent into the child (since now the child would have a copy of all the parent's properties instead of dynamically inheriting them.)

Comment: Normally, you should not want to call a constructor after deserialising an object; if there is some work to do after deserialisation, have a method that gets called for that purpose. Usually this will be different to what work ought to be done by the constructor when a fresh object is created.

Comment: All right. I had previously done it the way you suggest, and was wondering if there was a way to reduce the number of code paths so that fresh objects and deserialized objects would run the same code. I guess not, but I can live with that.